# Why does Rin die when her puppet tag is removed, but Obito doesn't?

Tags: naruto

We see Rin get struck by *chidori* in her chest in the same spot as Obito. So why does Rin die when Obito doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Obito survived because he made himself the 10-tails Jinchuriki shortly after being struck by Kakashi

> Both Rin Nohara and Obito Uchiha, who were branded with this cursed seal, had it removed by Kakashi Hatake's Chidori and Lightning Cutter respectively, **although Rin died while Obito survived by sealing the Ten-Tails into himself shortly after**.
>
> <sub>[Source](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Forbidden_Individual_Curse_Tag)</sub>

As seen with other Jinchuriki, their tailed beasts provide them with healing abilities to survive wounds that would otherwise be fatal

Comment: rin had the 3 tails though.

Comment: @KalElReyes I'm not sure how that is relevant to this answer

Comment: you said that tailed beast heals them and i said she had the 3 tails which should of healed her